# RubyMine remote feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian, virtual-machine, rubymine

I'm trying to setup RubyMine to connect over SSH and it actually works and I can specify the gem command working directory but I can't figure out how I can specify the working directory for bundler command when runned by RubyMine. It always executes the command with the project path from my windows machine (of course with this path it won't work). I already tryed `export PROJECT_PATH="<project folder>"`, but it's not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in march this year was this feature not supported. I dont know if RubyMine 6 have this feature.

[Link to Forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/443250?tstart=0)